# TSQL UPDATE or INSERT INTO Table from Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently working on a stored procedure in T-SQL on SQL Server 2012. I'm trying to update or insert into a table entries from another table.

Currently I can only update 1 record if the original Table has 1 entry for example. If I get 10 entries from the importing table, I would like to update 1 entry and add the remaining 9 records to my table.

Temporary Table (new values)

```
#tmpDelivery (VersionId INT, DeliveryModelId INT)
```

Delivery Table (original, to be updated)

```
[MySchema].[Delivery] (DeliveryId INT, DeliveryModelId INT, VersionId INT)
```

My current script looks like this:

```
UPDATE [MySchema].[Delivery]
SET    DeliveryModelId = [D].DeliveryModelId
FROM   #tmpDelivery [D]
WHERE  [MySchema].[Delivery].VersionId = 1
AND    [D].VersionId = [MySchema].[Delivery].VersionId

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT INTO [MySchema].[Delivery] ([DeliveryModelId], [VersionId])
    SELECT DeliveryModelId, VersionId
    FROM   #tmpDelivery
```

Somehow this query doesn't work correctly, it only updates 1 entry if  there is 1 existing for example...

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a `MERGE` statement in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the rowcount. Change your insert statement so it will only insert non existing records. You can use an outer join for this.

```
UPDATE [MySchema].[Delivery]
SET    DeliveryModelId = [D].DeliveryModelId
FROM   #tmpDelivery [D]
WHERE  [MySchema].[Delivery].VersionId = 1
AND    [D].VersionId = [MySchema].[Delivery].VersionId


INSERT INTO [MySchema].[Delivery] ([DeliveryModelId], [VersionId])
SELECT t.DeliveryModelId, t.VersionId
FROM   #tmpDelivery  t
  left join [MySchema].[Delivery] d on t.DeliveryModelId = d.DeliveryModelId 
                                   and t.VersionId = d.VersionId
where  d.DeliveryModelId is null
```